# Distributing tasks to modules in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list named *results* and a corresponding list of modules named *modules*, as well as some *options* that apply to all of the results and modules. Each module has a function *save* that needs to be called on the result that corresponds to it. So I can do something like the following:

```
q = deque(results)
for module in modules:
    module.save(q.popleft(), options)
```

or equivalently:

```
for i in range(len(modules)):
    modules[i].save(results[i], options)
```

This works great. However, there is no reason why I shouldn't do them all at the same time. But how to parallelize this in the best possible way is eluding me, even though it seems like it should be very straightforward. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Python 2.6.6, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items in `result` [are picklable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), then you using [Pool.apply_async](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) to run `module.save` concurrently like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools as IT
import logging

logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for module, result in IT.izip(modules, results):
        pool.apply_async(module.save, args=(result, options))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

In module.py:

```
import logging    
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def save():
    logger.debug('Starting save')
    ...
    logger.debug('Exiting save')
```

When run with `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, you'll see lots of debugging messages which will help you understand where Python is in the code for each process.

To silence logging, simply change that line to

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: I'm having a really strange problem with this. It runs all of the modules and they do everything fine, but then the program doesn't terminate. After everything is done, it just sits and then eventually crashes with MemoryError. Any idea why?

Comment: Do *all* of the `module.save` functions terminate? It's hard to debug this without seeing more code. Providing a [short runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem would be excellent, though I realize that might be hard to do. I know -- I'll edit the post to explain how to easily add logging statements. That way, you'll get a better idea where each process is right before the crash.

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful. :)